# SQL Multiple constraints on a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, check-constraints

I am working with sql server and the table of workers.
I need to add a column "Gender" and apply two constraints : check and default.

So i need to check that they gender is male/female and the default value should be "To be updated"

My query looks like that by it doesn't work:

```sql
ALTER TABLE Workers
ADD Gender VARCHAR(6) CHECK (Gender IN ('Male', 'Female'))
           DEFAULT 'To be updated'
```

Comment: `NULL` probably makes more sense as a default, I have never heard of anyone declaring their gender as `To be updated`. See also [Aaron Bertrand: Bad Habits: Avoiding NULL in SQL Server](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/10/database-design/bad-habits-avoiding-null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what "doesn't work" means, however `varchar(6)` doesn't accomodate the 13 characters of `'To be updated'`, and you need to include your default value as an allowable value. It's also a good idea to specifically name the constraints which enables you to easily reference them in future.

```
alter table Workers add 
  Gender varchar(13) 
    constraint GenderCheck check (Gender in ('Male', 'Female','To be updated') ) 
    constraint GenderDefault default ('To be updated');
```

[Working Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=758f8b87b389c067685e81fdffc19c01)

Also note - specifying `not null` when adding the column will apply the default to existing rows.

Comment: .... And you should give your constraints meaningful names.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree that's good advice I have amended

Comment: @Stu Thanks for your help. But when i run this query, my new column has still value "Null". Default value is not written. The same happens for my query, that's what i meant saying "it doesn't work"

Comment: @Lana please amend the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=758f8b87b389c067685e81fdffc19c01) to demonstrate.

Comment: @stu please see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93ec391107d9c1e3476ffdbc8f042bf6

Comment: @Lana you did not specify you expected to retrospectively apply to existing rows. However try also specifying `not null` Fiddle(https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dfee3888dd7d2bf2dc121bc1b37610c6)